# Deleting variable to not get print it out

Tags: python-3.x, printing

So I'm building my first calculator.

```
import math

# Adding two numbers
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

#Substract two numbers
def subst(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

#Multiply two numbers
def multi(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

#Divide two numbers
def divide(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

#Exponentiation of number
def expont(num1, num2):
    return pow(num1, num2)

#Square root
def sqrt(num1):
    return math.sqrt(num1)

#Sin
def sin(num1):
    return math.sin(num1)

#Cosinus
def cos(num1):
    return math.cos(num1)

#Tangent
def tan(num1):
    return math.tg(num1)




print("Select your operation:  \n" 
      "1.Add\n"  
      "2.Substract\n"
      "3.Multiply\n"
      "4.Divide\n"
      "5.Exponentiation\n"
      "6.Square root\n"
      "7.Sine\n"
      "8.Cosine\n"
      "9.Tangent")
operation = input("Select your operation 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9: ")
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

if operation == "1":
    print(add(num1,num2))
elif operation == "2":
    print(subst(num1,num2))
elif operation == "3":
    print(multi(num1,num2))
elif operation == "4":
    print(divide(num1, num2))
elif operation == "5":
    print(expont(num1,num2))
elif operation == "6":
    print(sqrt(num1))
elif operation == "7":
    print(sin(num1))
elif operation == "8":
    print(cos(num1))
else:
    print(tan(num1))
```

But I have a problem when I try to sine, cosine and tanget. As you see I want to take only one value, which is num1, but program is asking me to enter num2.
How can I prevent or maybe disable/delete the num2 for operation >= 7
I've tried using if, while statements, as well as del. But it doesn't work.
What should I do to disable num2 variable for operations that are bigger or equal to 7?

Comment: Just wrap your second input in an if statement like `if operation not in '6789':` and it won't execute for your last 4.

Comment: Thanks @Axe319! It helped me and program works as intended :) Thank you